# Is there a WCF Client event on disconnection/faulted?

Tags: wcf, client-server, nettcpbinding, faulted

I am using netTcpBinding in WCF and I would like to know, on the client side, when it disconnects or when its channel state goes to faulted, so that I can reconnect with the server.

The idea is creating a keep alive using channel events. I know it is possible to know that the client disconnected/went into faulted state in the server side using Channel.Faulted event. That way I can remove any subscriptions the client had on the server. However, I cannot reconnect the client on the server side. And that's exactly what I would like to do.